# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Maven build after installing eclipse WindowsBuilder plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, windowsbuilder

I am working with eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) Build id: 20220310-1457
and Maven. If I build without Maven - it works.

My Maven build also worked fine until a new plugin "Windows Builder" was installed. Since then I am getting the following error message:

```
constituent[40]: file:/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1285/0/.cp/
constituent[41]: file:/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/443/0/.cp/
constituent[42]: file:/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/20/0/.cp/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

I included the first 3 lines, because when I compare the old configurations, there are  a lot of new folders in the configuration/org.eclipse.osgi - these three folders are definitely not in the old configuration and that seems to be causing the problem. If I delete these folders eclipse doesn't work any more.

Just in case it is necessary this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Schulefant</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenMitarbeiterGUIAndCI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding><!-- Auf diese properties wird unten mit ${} zugegriffen -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version> 
        <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope><!-- wird nur bei mvn test durchgeführt, aber nicht bei mvn compile -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <!-- Configures the content of the created manifest -->
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Adds the classpath to the created manifest -->
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!-- Specifies that all dependencies of our application are found -->
                            <!-- Configures the main class of the application -->
                            <mainClass>RunMitarbeiterverwaltung</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The contents of `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi` changes all the time, you should never touch that. It is not likely to be related to the problem.

Comment: Do you mean [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)? How did you install it? Does the issue go away when uninstalling WindowBuilder? Can you reproduce it with the current Eclipse? Where do you get this error message? If there is something in the error log, please add the full error message to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem. The Admin installed the Nightly Build of WindowBuilder. If instead just the version 1.9.8 is installed everything works again.
[image]